# Error en Laravel: SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR: foreign key constraint "clients_record_id_foreign" cannot be implemented"?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, laravel-6

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Laravel y al momento de ejecutar PHP artisan migrate me manda este error. No logro comprender del todo qué es lo que está ocurriendo. ¿Alguien podría guiarme?

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  foreign key constraint "clients_record_id_foreign" cannot be implemented
>   DETAIL:  Key columns "record_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: uuid and bigint. (SQL: alter table "clients" add constraint "clients_record_id_foreign" foreign key ("record_id") references "records" ("id") on delete cascade)

[image]

[image: BD]

Código de Migraciones

Clients_Table

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class CreateClientsTable extends Migration
{
/**
* Run the migrations.
*
* @return void
* */
public function up()
{
Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();

        $table->uuid('record_id');
        $table->foreign('record_id')->references('id')->on('records')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('telephone');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('gender');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE clients ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();');
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('clients');
}
}
```

Records_Table

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class CreateRecordsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('records', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');

        $table->uuid('device_site_id');
        $table->foreign('device_site_id')->references('id')->on('device_site')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->string('gw_address',16);
        $table->string('gw_port',6);
        $table->string('gw_id');
        $table->string('ip',16);
        $table->string('mac',18);
        $table->string('url');
        $table->string('user_agent');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('records');
}
}
```

Comment: El error no es legible en una imagen, por favor edita y agregalo como texto

Comment: Existe una incompatibilidad de tipos entre tus llaves primaria y foránea, agrega tu código de las migraciones

Answer (score 1):

Como ya lo menciona [@BetaM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/128299/betam) es un error en los tipos de llave primaria en la tabla `records` y la llave foranea en la tabla `clients`

```
Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->uuid('record_id');
```

De igual manera debe ser en la tabla records

```
Schema::create('records', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // $table->bigIncrements('id'); <--- Es de tipo diferente
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
```

Comment: Y entonces que debe cambiar?